# font not changed even though imported within css stylesheet?

Tags: css, browser, fonts

I'm using a CMS and therefore can only amend the CSS file. I have the following code in that file:

```
<style>
 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap');




.h1_section_hero {

Font-family: 'Montserrat';

}

</style>
```

However it's not changing in the browser. I'm assuming that I don't have to download the font as i'm importing it within the file? thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your google font link is invalid, you are missing a `?` between `css2` and the `family` key:

```
'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap'
```

If you were to open both urls into your browser you will see that your original url is broken, and that the correct one above shows the fonts.

Comment: thanks but it does have the question mark jamie, I may have deleted it my mistake when indenting the code here..

Comment: Oh okay no problem, sorry it wasn't the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate link to the stylesheet rather than trying to import. The markup below is taken from the Google Fonts API doc and works just fine in my browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Crimson+Pro">
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: 'Crimson Pro', serif;
        font-size: 48px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Making the Web Beautiful!</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks but i've also tried this, however it is still not showing. What's also bizzare is that when I change the font in the chrome dev tools it still doesn't show..

Comment: @gilesj You said this is on a CMS? Is there an admin you can ask for support?

Comment: yeh i'll be chasing tomorrow, just wanted to see if there's anything I could try out today

Comment: Understood. My hypothesis is that there is something on the CMS server blocking the import. An admin can tell you what’s happening and probably give you a workaround. Good luck.